# discord.py 1.7.3 - Send messages to a specific user id ( on_ready )

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm having the issue where I send a dm message (message var) to each user id on a list (memberlist var), and when I try to send it, I get an error saying: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

Code:

```
client = discord.Client()
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f"\n{Color.GREEN} > {Color.WHITE} Logged in as: {client.user.name}")
        # send message to each member in memberlist
        for member in memberslist:
            print(member)       
            str(member)     
            user = client.get_user(member)
            await user.send(message)
            print(f"\n{Color.GREEN} > {Color.WHITE} Message sent to {client.get_user(member).name}")
        print(f"\n{Color.GREEN} > {Color.WHITE} Done!\n")
```

Comment: What is `str(member)` supposed to do? Also `get_user` won't work in on ready because there is no cache.

Comment: It converts member to a string, since now user ids are strings.

Comment: #1: It does nothing. #2: The opposite is true. All IDs are ints.

Answer (score 1):

The [`get_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Client.get_user) method only looks through the members cache and, at the time of your `get_user` calls, your bot's members cache is empty thus returning `None`s and leading you to this error.

What you can do instead is manually fetch the user using the [`fetch_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Client.fetch_user) coroutine.

Comment: Now I get `discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 0)˙` lol.

Answer (score 0):

It would look like this, I have tested the code and it works. Do note that the bot needs to share a server with a user to be able to message them (plus the users dms need to be accepting messages from server members).

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('bot is ready')
  user = await client.fetch_user(userid)
  await user.send(message)
```